# Table columns not of equal size in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, layout, html-table, bootstrap-4

I'm migrating a project to Bootstrap 4. In previous Bootstrap 3 version all three columns were of equal width. In Bootstrap 4 the first column is very wide and other two columns are squeezed together on far right side.

How it was before:

[image]

How it is now:

[image]

As you can see the problem on the 2nd picture, the first column just takes too much space and I need all three columns to be of equal size. The html looks like this:

```html
<table id="mDataTable" data-cols-num="6" class="table" aria-describedby="mDataTable_info">
  <thead>
    <tr class="search-cols" style="display: none;" role="row"></tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td class="header-action-row" style="border:none; cursor:default;" colspan="11">
        <h5 class='datatable-title'><span class='fa fa-list'></span>&nbsp; @SharedResources.Index.ListOfBradenScale</h5>
        <div class="action-images pull-right">
          <div class="add-img fa fa-plus-circle" style="cursor:pointer;" title="@SharedResources.Index.Add" data-bind="click: mainDataAdd"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,1)}, css: mainDataUserNameIcon">@SharedResources.Index.Employee</th>
      <th data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,2)}, css: mainDataDateAndTimeIcon">@SharedResources.Index.Date</th>
      <th data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,3)}, css: mainDataCalculateIcon">@SharedResources.Index.Risk</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr data-bind="visible: mainData() == null || mainData().length < 1">
    <td data-bind="attr: { 'colspan': 5 }">
      <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"> @SharedResources.Index.NoData</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: mainData">
    <tr style="cursor:pointer;" data-bind="click :$parent.mainDataSelectRow.bind($data,$index()),
                        css: { 'row-selected': $parent.mainDataSelectedRowPosition() != null && $index() == $parent.mainDataSelectedRowPosition(), 'for-delete': ForDelete() == true  }">
      <td class="col-4" data-bind="text: UserName, click: $root.mainDataDetails, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete} "> </td>
      <td class="col-4" data-bind="text: DateAndTime, click: $root.mainDataDetails, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete}  "></td>
      <td class="col-4" data-bind="text: CalculateRisk, click: $root.mainDataDetails, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete}  "></td>
      <td class="action-column">
        <div class="row-delete fa fa-copy icon-blue" title="@SharedResources.Index.CopyIntoNewEntry" data-bind="click: $parent.copyIntoNew, visible: ForDelete() == false"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="action-column">
        <div class="row-delete fa fa-share icon-flip" title="@SharedResources.Index.Undo" style="color: #096224; cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: $parent.mainDataUndoRemove, visible: ForDelete() == true"></div>
        <div class="row-delete fa fa-minus-circle icon-delete" title="@SharedResources.Index.Delete" data-bind="click: CanDelete()? $parent.mainDataRemove: null, visible: ForDelete() == false, css:{'icon-disabled': CanDelete() == false}"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove class="col-4" from the code.

Comment: Tried, but i get this: http://prntscr.com/kgielp EDIT: I forgot to remove one  **<td class = col-4>**, now it works!

Answer (score 2):

add class `row` to `tr`.Since the class `row` contains `display:flex;`,its `flex-items` render as expected.

UPDATE:
 add `mx-0` with row class and wrap those icons within the last `<td class="col-4">` itself

If you don't want the `td` to be in grid columns and you want to make the entire table as responsive then remove `col-4` from td and `row mx-0` from `tr`.Wrap the table within `<div class="table-responsive">`